# Why is the xms xmx amount in linux process different from elasticsearch stats?

Tags: elasticsearch

So i defined both xms and xmx with value of **8G** in my docker file

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms8g -Xmx8g"
```

Here's the output of `ps -auwx`

```
docker exec -it myContainer ps -auwx | grep -i elastic
elastic+     1  5.3 56.7 14090492 9320752 ?    SLsl Jul11  53:07 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcM
```

Which is strange .. why it displays 1G instead of 8G per definition. So i continued checking the elastic process itself with:

```
docker exec -it myContainer curl 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats?pretty=true' | grep heap
          "heap_used_in_bytes" : 1202774752,
          "heap_used_percent" : 14,
          "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 8537636864,
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 8537636864,
          "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 111854000,
          "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 118992896
```

Which seems to be correct.

Why would `ps -auwx` displays 1G instead of 8G ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Xms1g -Xmx1g` are the default parameters for the elasticsearch start script, they are configured in the `jvm.options` file, the `ES_JAVA_OPTS` variable allows you to change the values for `Xms` and `Xmx`.

When you call the jvm with duplicate `Xms` and `Xmx` parameters, the ones most on the right of the command will be used, since the `ES_JAVA_OPTS` are present on the command call after the default values, they will be used.

Look into the full command of your elasticsearch instance and you will see the `-Xms8g -Xmx8g` configuration, the result of your `ps` was probably truncated.